# Display a new div in-line directly after content of parent div?

Tags: html, css

I have a banner that's width is set to `100%`.
I then have another div set at `30px` nested within the main div placed at the end of the first div. This close-ban div has the background image of a close icon and the javascript is set so when a user hits the div the entire banner hides.

I want to position this close-bar div immediately after the text inside of the div labeled banner.

This is what it should look like

[this is a banner it has text inside of it [X]]

```
<div id="banner">this is a banner it has text inside of it<div id="close-ban"></div></div>
```

Comment: What CSS do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set float left for banner and float right for close-ban. Like this:

```css
#banner {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
#close-ban {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">this is a banner it has text inside of it<div id="close-ban">close</div></div>
```

or create a container with 100% width and put inside it banner and close-ban divs, like this:

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
}
#banner {
  float: left;
}
#close-ban {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="banner">this is a banner it has text inside of it <div id="close-ban">close</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider making the close-ban a span element rather than a div element. That way it will be placed inline with your other HTML:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp
(The `span` tag is formatted the same as an `inline-block`. You could alternatively add `display:inline-block` in the CSS for your close-ban)

Keep in mind that if your text takes up the width of your top ban, it will push the close-ban to the next line with the method above. To avoid this, you could alternatively look into positioning the close-ban relative to the screen or the banner: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp